# How to mount a Vue component on a static page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

How can I mount a Vue component in an existing HTML page?
I tried for hours now, and my latest try looks like this:

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('MyComponent', require('./MyComponent.vue'));
```

MyComponent.vue:

```
<template>
   <H2>Hi</H2>
</template>
<script setup>
    console.log('setup')
</script>
<script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import { Chat } from '@chat-ui/vue3'
    export default {
        name: 'MyComponent',
        data() {
        },
        mounted() {
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in the HTML I added a `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` Element.

I get the following error when I want to build it via Vite:
"default" is not exported by "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js", imported by "src/main.js".

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you should adjust the way you import Vue. Here's the corrected version of your `main.js` file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'; // Import createApp instead of importing Vue directly
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```